# Initial animate function not working, but working when users click thereafter

Tags: jquery, fade

I've only just learned how to use jquery so bear with me.

http://jsfiddle.net/mariabarrette/KqjD3/20/

There is the site I am working on. I am happy with everything except for the initial animate function. Wwhat I mean is that when the user clicks "about" or "resume" or "contact" for the FIRST time when visiting the site, the content does not fade in. After the user has viewed one section and changes from about to contact to resume, there are no problems, the content fades in and out appropriately. It is just that first time that the content does not fade in.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using jQuery v1.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set hidden to

```
.hidden {opacity:0; height:0 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KqjD3/22/

It does not work before because you had display none so there is no opacity for it to animate.

Also

```
<div id="contactcontent" class="hidden" class="opacity0">
```

can change to

```
<div id="contactcontent" class="opacity0">
```

that'll fix your problem without changing hidden, there are a lot more optimization which you can do but I will leave that up to you